# read function in net_device linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am developing a small net device in linux. When i gone through the

struct net_device_ops

{

.ndo_start_xmit = transfer

}

.ndo_start_xmit is for transfering data from net device to hardware. 
But how will i come to know when new a data arrives to the net device/Hardware. 
How to handle a read() in net_device? or How it handled in net_device ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is `netif_rx` defined in [linux/netdevice.h](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/netdevice.h;h=02e0f6b156c3f2dc7c2cae5c663cbdbfd6341484;hb=7a280cf512053137a37da2801eac73a8842fa50d#l2162) and declared in [net/core/dev.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=net/core/dev.c;h=d0cbc93fcf32d94db2b909274dd60a9fe88cc80e;hb=7a280cf512053137a37da2801eac73a8842fa50d#l3076)